# CREATE TABLE syntax need HASH keyword explicitly in YugabyteDB YCQL?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

We are using YSQL on YugabyteDB. Below table syntax create table with hash sharding:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id bpchar NOT NULL,
    company_name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id HASH)
);
```

Does below table syntax creates the table with range sharding or hash sharding?

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id bpchar NOT NULL,
    company_name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the first column of a PRIMARY KEY or INDEX is taken to be the HASH column unless it is denoted as ASC or DESC which would indicate a RANGE column. The default RANGE column order is ASC if unspecified after the first column.

If the primary key is as shown in below table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.table1
(
    customer_id uuid NOT NULL,
    item_id uuid NOT NULL,
    kind character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    details character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, kind, item_id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  IF NOT EXISTS  unique_customer_id ON table1(customer_id);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  IF NOT EXISTS unique_item ON table1(customer_id, kind) WHERE kind='BAD' OR kind='SLOW';
```

The PRIMARY KEY will be sharded on `customer_id`, and it will be sorted in `kind, item_id` order ascending.
In the first index `unique_customer_id`, that index will be sharded on the `customer_id` field. In the second index `unique_item`, it will be sharded on `customer_id`, with the `kind` field being sorted in ascending order within each `customer_id`. Your sample query will be slow/bad because you have to scan all `customer_id` shards for the specified `kind` field.